# How to block/freeze an embedded Pinterest board from scrolling down?

Tags: css, overflow, pinterest

I have a Pinterest board embedded, which is taking the complete width at the top of the page.

I want that if I scroll down, the page itself directly scrolls down; not the embedded Pinterest board.

I've tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536453/5802289):

```
#pinterest-container > span {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but the board is still scrollable.

I have also tried with javascript, but somehow it is not being inserted in my html. Neither:

```
var getThis = $('#pinterest-container > span:eq(0) > span:eq(1) > span:eq(0)');
$(getThis).css("overflow", "hidden");
```

nor:

```
var getThis = $('#pinterest-container > span:eq(0) > span:eq(1) > span:eq(0)');
$(getThis).addClass("hide-overflow");
```

And here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w57osokq/

Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311430/5802289) showed me the way:

The container of the Pinterest board with the scrollbar is `<span class="PIN_xxxxx_bd"  ...>`. Then, the following CSS is needed:

```
<style>
    #pinterest-container [class$=_bd] {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
</style>
```